# How to change app navbar color when app is in drawer in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, android-drawer

I need to change the color of the apps navbar when app is in the drawer.

I tried status bar plugin but it only chnage the color of the status bar when app is open on screen.

```
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#e13c31');
```

and

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="red" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

I want to change Hrythm apps navbar color to red like message app has its own color which is blue.

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: Change into variable.scss primary color

Comment: Which paramaeter should i change? If its primary then my primary color is set to blue then why its black when my app is open in drawer. @MDKhali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending lots of time searching for this issue, I finally found the solution.
I used the "Header Color" plugin to change the color of the header when the app is in the drawer.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/header-color/

Answer (score 0):

**1.****ionic 3**

```
.toolbar-background {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**2.****older version**

```
<ion-navbar *navbar primary></ion-navbar>
<ion-navbar *navbar secondary></ion-navbar>
<ion-navbar *navbar danger></ion-navbar>
```

**3.** In `variable.scss` I added the property as `navbarColor: #009688`

```
$colors: (
  primary:     #387ef5,
  secondary:   #32db64,
  danger:      #f53d3d,
  light:       #f4f4f4,
  dark:        #222,
  favorite:    #69BB7B,
  navbarColor: #009688
);
```

And added in my home.html at the ion-navbar element.

```
<ion-navbar color='navbarColor'></ion-navbar>
```

**4.** With Ionic 2 rc2 we have the following variables we can use to change the toolbar appearance:

```
$toolbar-background
$toolbar-border-color
$toolbar-text-color
$toolbar-active-color
$toolbar-inactive-color
```

**5.**

```
<ion-navbar no-border-bottom [color]="isAndroid ? 'primary' : 'light'">
```

**6.**

```
<ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Not Delivered Details</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```